# Stream .m4a audio file from rtsp url objective-c ios

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, avplayer, rtsp

Sorry for bad Engilsh.

I am new to iOS development.And I am trying to create a client application which **stream .m4a audio file** from stream url

**rtsp://192.168.1.50:1935/TestServer/abc.m4a**

and play it on button click.

I have tried almost every thing which I can find but I was not able to get and play stream. 
There is my code which play audio from http url

```
  - (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {


    NSString *str = @"http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/AAC/Nero_Soundtrax/NeroSoundTrax_test1_AAC-LC_v4_Stereo_CBR_96kbps_44100Hz.m4a";
    NSString *urlStr = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSURL * mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:mediaURL];


    [player play];

}
```

but I want to play audio file from this type of url. **rtsp://192.168.1.50:1935/TestServer/abc.m4a**

*i tested my streaming url on VLC to verify. It works perfect but when I put that url on button click code it didn't work.*

I try to use ffmpeg library but did not find luck in that.

Answer (score 0):

Try register audio session category before playing.

```
 - (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];
    NSString *str = @"http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/AAC/Nero_Soundtrax/NeroSoundTrax_test1_AAC-LC_v4_Stereo_CBR_96kbps_44100Hz.m4a";
    NSString *urlStr = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSURL * mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:mediaURL];


    [player play];

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank's for the reply.
but i'm try to stream audio from rtsp url  like thise:
rtsp://192.168.1.50:1935/TestServer/abc.m4a

Comment: no i didn't want to do that

i'm trying to stream live with out downloading it. and from RTSP type url.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich, how does AVAudioSession belong to downloading video ?

Comment: i'm not saying that AVAudioSession in used for downloading. i'm jest explaining  the question.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich, you need to activate your audio session before using AVPlayer, so you need to set category

Comment: Can you tell me what i need to learn for .m4a audio streaming from rtsp url.
any link ???

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich, you can download sample from apple, and try modify it - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I'm not that much good in that. can you share any tutorial link for that.
i look but couldn't find a readable one. Sorry for asking stupid think's.

Answer (score 0):

Standard iOS frameworks do not support RTSP playback, so you will have to use some third-party solution.

Hope this post helps:
https://gist.github.com/oc2pcoj/e55795550984d205d109

Comment: Can you point one which is simple and easy to use. I'm new in that. i try to understand this one
https://github.com/iMoreApps/ffmpeg-avplayer-for-ios-tvos
but couldn't able to do that. so plz give me the link . Thank's